# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1

Tags: java, android

I have problem with android programming.
I have three Classes.

**Main2_Activity Class**

```
public class Main2_Activity extends Activity{
    ArrayList<Estekhare> estekhareHa = new ArrayList<Estekhare>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TextView txt_soore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_soore);
        final TextView txt_aye = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_aye);
        final TextView txt_safhe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_safhe);
        final TextView txt_koli = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_koli);
        final TextView txt_moamele = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_moamele);
        final TextView txt_ezdevaj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_ezdevaj);
        final TextView txt_natije = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_natije);
        final TextView txt_main_aye = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_main_aye);
        final TextView txt_translate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_translate);

        Button btnAgain=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAgain);

        Cursor cursor = G.DB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Sheet1", null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Estekhare estekhare = new Estekhare();
            estekhare.natije = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("natije"));
            estekhare.koli = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("koli"));
            estekhare.ezdevaj = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ezdevaj"));
            estekhare.moamele = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("moamele"));
            estekhare.soore = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("soore"));
            estekhare.aye = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("aye"));
            estekhare.safhe = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("safhe"));

            estekhare.main_translate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("main_translate"));

            estekhareHa.add(estekhare);
        }
        cursor.close();

        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(estekhareHa.size());
        Estekhare estekhare = estekhareHa.get(n);
        txt_soore.setText(estekhare.soore);
        txt_aye.setText(estekhare.aye);
        txt_safhe.setText(estekhare.safhe);
        txt_koli.setText(estekhare.koli);
        txt_moamele.setText(estekhare.moamele);
        txt_ezdevaj.setText(estekhare.ezdevaj);
        txt_natije.setText(estekhare.natije);
        txt_main_aye.setText(estekhare.main_aye);
        txt_translate.setText(estekhare.main_translate);
```

**Estekhare Class**

```
public class Estekhare {       
    public String natije;    
    public String koli;
    public String ezdevaj;
    public String moamele;
    public String soore;
    public String aye;
    public String safhe;
    public String main_aye;
    public String main_translate;
}
```

**G Class**

```
public class G extends Application{
    public static SQLiteDatabase DB;
    public static Context context;
    public static final String DIR_SDCARD=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    public static String DIR_DATABASE;
    private final String   dbName = "natije_estekhare.sqlite";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context=getApplicationContext();
        DIR_DATABASE= DIR_SDCARD +"/Android/data/"+ context.getPackageName()+ "/database/";
        new File(DIR_DATABASE).mkdirs();
        prepareDB();
    }
    public boolean prepareDB() {
        try {
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            InputStream is = G.context.getAssets().open(dbName);

            if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                File DB_PATH = new File(DIR_DATABASE + "/" + dbName);
                logger("SD MOUNTED");
                if (DB_PATH.exists()) {
                    logger("DB exist");
                    DB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH, null);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    logger("DB NOT exist");
                    if (copy(new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH), is)) {
                        logger("Copy Success");
                        DB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH, null);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        logger("Copy Faild");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                logger("SD NOT MOUNTED");
                DIR_DATABASE = getFilesDir().toString();
                File dbFile = new File(getFilesDir().toString() + "/" + dbName);
                if (dbFile.exists()) {
                    logger("DB exist");
                    DB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile, null);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    logger("DB NOT exist");
                    FileOutputStream os = openFileOutput(dbName, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    if (copy(os, is)) {
                        logger("Copy Success");
                        DB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile, null);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        logger("Copy Faild");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean copy(OutputStream os, InputStream is) {
        try {
            int readed = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            while ((readed = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, readed);
            }
            try {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                os.flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                os.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void logger(String Message){
        Log.i("LOG", Message);
    }
}
```

When I Run this program, it crashes. How to solve the problem?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{amir.badiei.app.estekhareapp/amir.badiei.app.estekhareapp.Main2_Activity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.at amir.badiei.app.estekhareapp.Main2_Activity.onCreate(Main2_Activity.java:47).
```

Comment: Reformat your code snippet, it's not quite readable!

Answer (score 2):

If a column doesn't exist, then cursor.getColumnIndex will return -1.

I'd start checking to make sure your Sheet1 table has all of the columns you are trying to access and that they are indeed named exactly the way you are specifying in your code.  Otherwise when you try to get the data from the cursor for a column of -1, you'll get the IllegalStateException.